# Push notifications failing because of invalid tokens being sent from GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I noticed an issue in our backend that started happening in October. October 15th to be precise. It seems that I am getting invalid tokens from GCM on Android, which my backend is then storing and failing to send push notifications too.

One thing to note is that I'm using a deprecated api. Which may be part of the issue, but I have no way to confirm. [This is the API I'm using to register users with GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid).

The tokens I'm getting back have a formatting that I'm not familiar with. This is what a valid token looks like for me, starts with `APA9`.

```
Valid token: APA91bFolo25yEfP2_3wUt3bPO08S3Hz1NBpJbyWkW5_hhsQ6WggOogQOXPYohmh
```

However I'm getting back tokens that look like this:

```
Invalid token: csPVRloDPzc%3AAPA91bFFU2DOGLg3hXoOvQ9vnhN3gMA4aalBAhGGJzAqt4Jtyy
```

Notice the extra characters at the start before the usual APA9. If I remove these extra characters, the token is still invalid. So I'm unsure what the exact issue is. The issue is happening very randomly, sometimes I get the correct tokens, sometimes I don't.

Obviously using a deprecated API is not ideal at all, and that will be the first thing I change, however this problem started on it's own, without any code changes, around the date I mentioned.

Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is what a valid token looks like for me, starts with APA9.

A token does not have to start with APA9 to be valid. In my database I have IDs starting with just about any letter (but never a number).

One thing all my IDs have in common though, is a `:` as the 12th character, and `APA9` right after that.

Your 'invalid' token that looks like `csPVRloDPzc%3AAPA91bFFU2DOGLg3hXoOvQ9vnhN3gMA4aalBAhGGJzAqt4Jtyy` also has one as the 12th character, but it appears to be URL encoded as `%3A`.

I suspect that if you decode that, it will suddenly be a valid ID.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I decoded the token, and put it into the FCM Diagnostics tool on the Google Play developer console but it's throwing an error, telling me to enter a valid token. So I can only assume it's still invalid.

Comment: @RED_ I see. But is `APA91bFolo25yEfP2_3wUt3bPO08S3Hz1NBpJbyWkW5_hhsQ6WggOogQOXPYohmh` valid? If I test it, it says it's not

Comment: Whoops you're correct, I was only getting partial token's from the page I copied them from. I checked both against the full token and they both showed up after being decoded. Something so simple that me and a backend dev missed. +1 and marked as answer.